# Which engine oil is my manual telling me to use?

Tags: oil

I have attached a pic from my vehicle manual which shows the engine oil I need to use.  It lists the different models the car comes in e.g. 1.6, 2.0, 2.7.  At

I have a 2.0.  At first I thought whatever in the same row at the previous coloumn is the correct oil but there are more oils in the first row which do not have a car in the next coloumn so that cant be correct.

Basically all I see is a list of oils and not sure which is correct for my car.  I also note on some it says above 18c, above 13c etc but what does this mean?

Anyway please explain and tell me what oil is my manual telling me to use.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: That's not above 18C and 13C, but -18C and -13C, it's a very important difference!

Answer (score 2):

Which oil to use depends on the coldest temperatures the vehicle will be exposed to.

All oils thicken as the temperature drops, and thin as the temperature rises.
If the oil is too thick, it won't flow through the engine properly. This will severely damage or destroy your engine.
If the oil is too thin, it will also not lubricate properly, because it flows too easily. Again, damaged or destroyed engine.

Where I live, it never drops as low as -7C, so I would use a 20w50 oil.
I don't know where you live, or what the weather is like there, so I can't say which you need.

Comment: why does it also mention 5w-20 and 5w-30, why do they have no temperatures?

Comment: I agree, 20w-50 is super thick compared to 5W-20 and it is odd to see both on the list for the same vehicle. I would contact a dealer for your make and get clarification. Did you look if there was any marking on the oil fill cap?

Comment: @JamesWilson I'm guessing, but it would be reasonable to assume that those extremely thin oils are safe down to sufficiently cold (-40c ish) that it's just not an issue.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it for warm climates, 20w50 ish isn't all that uncommon. And note there that it's not for use in places with temperatures below -7C. From memory (i'll check the manual tonight) my GSXR has 20w50 in it.

Comment: @Leliel I agree but none of the climates shown would be considered "warm", and the temperature range is very narrow considering the viscosity difference. It just seems strange.

Comment: "for warm climates, 20w50 ish isn't all that uncommon" It depends on the car, but for modern (i.e. less than 10 years old) European cars, 20W50 is positively "agricultural." 5W30 or even 0W30 would be more common, down to about -20C. But then, I don't expect to burn 1L of oil between changes at *30,000 Km intervals* in a 10-year-old engine, not 1L per 1500 Km as per the OP's chart!